# Android Centering RecyclerView between toolbar and custom view

Tags: android

I create a media player app and I successfully managed to align the custom view witch is a `Media Controller` at the bottom of my main layout and the toolbar witch is at the top of layout from the XML.

Now I have a Layout with `RecyclerView` that I want to fit between `toolbar` and `Controller`, I managed to align only top below `Toolbar` but on the bottom `Controller` and `Layout` overlap.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, toolbar.getId());
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, musicController.getId());
mainLayout.addView(musicListLayout, params);
```

Also I have tried setting the Height of layout with         `mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight() - musicController.getMeasuredHeight()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my problem was to set an Id for the `controller` because it was created programatically.